# Reach type member inside class

Tags: c#, class

I have 2 types as defined below:

```
public class T1
{
    public int A1;
    public int B1;
}

public class T2
{
    public int A2;
    public int B2;
}
```

I have a class that contains lists of T1 and T2:

```
public class Topology
{
    public List<T1> T1s;
    public List<T2> T2s;
}
```

I want to create a method in T2 class and want to reach T1s variables. How can i do that?

Comment: Well which *instance* of `T1` do you want to use the variables from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing a T1 reference into T2 via a constructor?

```
public class T2
{
    private T1 _t1Reference;

    public int A2;
    public int B2;

    public T2(T1 t1Reference)
    {
       _t1Reference = t1Reference;    
    }

    public void T2Method()
    {
       //Access _t1Reference here 
    }
}
```

Or passing a reference to the T1 instance via T2's method parameters?

```
public class T2
{
    public int A2;
    public int B2;

    public void T2Method(T1 t1Reference)
    {
       //Access t1Reference here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a public method in T2 and pass object of T1 in parameter.

```
public class T2
{
    public int A2;
    public int B2;

    public void YourMethod(T1 t1)
    {
       string a1 = t1.A1;
       string b1 = t1.B1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some ways to acheive

1- Inherit T2 from T1,

2- Pass T1 as method parameter